# How to order data frames of a list in R considering names of each one of them

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem with a list of data frames in R. I have a list of five data frames in R, they are ordered by their name, for example first is `d1`, second `d2`, etc. and final is `d5`. The structure of my list is the next:

```
structure(list(d1 = structure(list(x = c("001", "002", "003", 
"004", "005", "006"), y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), z1 = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    d2 = structure(list(x = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
    "006", "007"), y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), z2 = c(2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z2"), row.names = c(NA, 
    7L), class = "data.frame"), d3 = structure(list(x = c("001", 
    "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008"), y = c(1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), z3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("x", 
    "y", "z3"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame"), 
    d4 = structure(list(x = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
    "006", "007", "008", "009"), y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), z4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("x", "y", 
    "z4"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame"), d5 = structure(list(
        x = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", 
        "008", "009", "010"), y = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1), z5 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("x", 
    "y", "z5"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("d1", 
"d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"))
```

My problem is I can have more than five elements and I need to put them in descending order considering their name, for example I want in first position `a5`, second position `a4`, third position `a3`, second position `a2` and final position `a1`. I would like something like this:

```
list

a5

x   y z5
001 1 5

a4

x   y z4
001 1 4

a3

x   y z3
001 1 3

a2

x   y z2
001 1 2

a1

x   y z1
001 1 1
```

I wait this is possible to make in R, I was trying to use `llply` from `plyr` package but I don't get that result. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mixedorder` from the `gtools` package and assuming that your list is dat:

```
library(gtools)
dat[rev(mixedorder(names(dat)))]
```

Or as propsed by the OP using regular expression:

```
df.names=names(list) 
df.names=df.names[order(as.integer(sub("[a-z]", "", df.names)),
                        decreasing = TRUE)]   
list=list[df.names]
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy but I had problems when I have a list of 15 data frames `a1`, `a2`, `a15` y got all of them in dirsorder. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: For example instead of getting `a11`,`a10`,`a9`,...,`a1` I got `a11`,`a10`,`a1`,`a9`,...,`a2` dear @agstudy

Comment: But I solve this with next code: `df.names=names(list)` `df.names=df.names[order(as.integer(sub("[a-z]", "", df.names)),decreasing = TRUE)]` and `list=list[df.names]` Thanks @agstudy

Comment: @Duck your solution is a good one also, without any external package.  I edit my answer to add yours.

Comment: Thanks dear @agstudy I am new with list but I made a lot of things prefer to individual data frames.

Comment: +1 another option that avoids an external package: `rev(order(nchar(names(dat)), names(dat)))`